# CGI: Execute python script as root

Tags: python, apache, cgi

I'm attempting to execute *foo.py* from **mysite.com/foo.py**, however the script requires access to directories that would normally require `sudo -i` root access first. `chmod u+s foo.py` still doesn't give the script enough permission. What can I do so the script has root access? Thank you!

Comment: Surely all you've done there is change the permissions of the script itself, which isn't going to change the access the script has. You either need to change the permissions of the directory you're trying to access or incorporate sudo into your script, something like that.

Comment: Have you seen what user the script runs as? I assume you're running this from a webserver, so it could be the apache user or something similar.

Comment: Yes it is as apache, and that is a contributing factor. I've fixed my problem by simply using the /tmp/ directory. However, for those who stumble on this problem with something similar I would recommend either that or analyzing your execution permissions (for the user executing, e.g. Apache as opposed to root).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `chmod 777 foo.py` or `chmod +x foo.py`? Those are generally the commands used to give  file permission to run.

Comment: Yes, and the error I'm getting is /backup/dbbackup/ directory is permission denied to me, even with the file's perms being 4775.

Comment: Are you running the code as sudo? Also, have you tried running `sudo nautilus`? This would allow you to go into the folders and see the permissions and change them manually.

Comment: Since it's being run via HTTP request a-la CGI lib, no.